# grunt and gulp confusions - running a gulp within another project that has gulp

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower, gulp

This is probably going to sound stupid as can be, but please bear with me. I am having trouble with it.

I am working on a project that uses `Grunt` to compile and construct its distribution. However, it uses another library known as `prism`, which you can find at **http://prismjs.com**

Now, `prism` is a wonderful library, and I do like it. However I am installing it to my application using `bower` - it's simple enough, `bower install prism --save-dev`

Now the problem I run into is that *prism* downloads as its own source code - which happens to not have the compiled source I need, but rather a `gulpfile.js` that creates the compiled source. I'm typically pretty happy with that, I do love me some gulping goodness - but in this situation I'm at a bit of a loss because I've never encountered a situation where I was using `grunt` to also use `gulp`.

### Too Long; Didn't Read

The folder structure ends up like this;

```
/-root
 | - bower_components
 | - - bootstrap
 | - - jquery
 | - - jquery-colorbox
 | - - prism
 | - - - components
 | - - - plugins
 | - - - themes
 | - - - vendor
 | - - - .bower.json
 | - - - bower.json
 | - - - components.js
 | - - - gulpfile.js
 | - - - package.json
 | .gitignore
 | bower.json
 | Gruntfile.js
 | package.json
 | README.md
```

So what I need to do is figure out how to run `/bower_components/prism/gulp.js` **from** `/gruntfile.js`, such that it produces the compiled result, which my `gruntfile.js` can then use to dispatch out to my `/dist` folder.

I do know that I can just clone the `prism` repository separately and do it, but I wanted the experience of building my library to be self contained, all in one sort of thing. Is this possible? Or am I just dumb?

Comment: create a task for executing from the command line and actually run gulp?

Comment: I am a little confused by what you mean _"create a task for executing from the command line"_ - I guess what I am asking, is there a way to make a command in grunt that can run the gulpfile in another directory?

Comment: Yes - it's no different from running an arbitrary command (the task creates a child process and executes it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll develop a little what [@Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940454/grunt-and-gulp-confusions-running-a-gulp-within-another-project-that-has-gulp#comment40611506_25940454) said.

You can indeed run commands directly from your `Gruntfile` by using the [grunt-exec plugin](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) or the [grunt-shell one](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell).

A task for your needs could be something like this, using **grunt-shell**

```
shell: {
  launchPrism: {
    command: 'gulp',
    execOptions: {
      cwd: 'bower_components/prism'
    }
  }
}
```

You still need to run a `npm install` in the *prism* directory, but you could also add this to the executed command or in your project install